# R - read_csv without using paste

Tags: r

Use the read_csv function to read each of the files you got in the files object with code below:

```r
path <- system.file("extdata", package = "dslabs") 
files <- list.files(path) 
files
```

I tried this code below but I get "vroom_ error. Please help.

```
for (f in files){
  read_csv(f)
}
```

Comment: Restart R and try again - none of the code you show should use the `vroom` package. You shouldn't even have the `vroom` package loaded.

Comment: FYI, your `for` loop is reading the files and immediately discarding their data. Perhaps you want to store it after reading it in? BTW, `readr` imports `vroom`, and `read_csv` is just a wrapper around `read_delim` which calls `vroom::vroom`. @GregorThomas

Comment: If you're getting an error, don't keep it a secret from us: please post the literal text from the error. If it talks about file format, then it might be useful to paste the first few raw lines of the file into a code block (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the comments. This is the error I am getting. > for (f in files){
+   read_csv(f)
+ }
Error in vroom_(file, delim = delim %||% col_types$delim, col_names = col_names,  :                                     0s
  embedded nul in string: '<d0><cf>\021<U+0871>\032<e1>'

Answer (score 1):

First, in `list.files` you should set `full.names=TRUE` to include the whole path. Next, if you look into `files`, there are also .xls and .pdf files included. You may want to filter just for .csv files, which can easily be done using `grep`.

```
files <- list.files(path, full.names=TRUE)
files <- grep('.csv$', files, value=TRUE)
```

However, even then `readr::read_csv` complains about column issues.

```
lst <- readr::read_csv(files)
# Error: Files must all have 2 columns:
#   * File 2 has 57 columns
```

To avoid editing the columns by hand, I recommend to use `rio::import_list` instead, which gives just a warning, that a column name was guessed and can be changed if needed. You may even include the .xls in the `grep`.

```
files <- grep('.csv$|.xls', files, value=TRUE)
lst <- rio::import_list(files)
```

Note that `rio::import_list` (as well as `readr::read_csv`) is vectorized, so you won't need a loop.

---

*Data:*

```
path <- system.file("extdata", package="dslabs")
```